# mobile safari cannot focus on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web-applications, mobile-safari

I'm not trying to auto focus on textarea, just when the user clicks on it. However it simply doesn't work sometimes. The user clicks on the textarea but no keyboard pops up. Why?

Try my website: `http://162.243.161.127` on mobile safari. On the top menu click on chat, you should see a textarea that you can type in. Half the time focusing on it doesn't work. Where do I begin to debug, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, pesky :hovers. They're terrible on touch devices, for so many reasons..

Remove this and see if it helps.

```
.chatInputContainer:hover .image {
    display: block
}
```

Then you'll need to figure out a way to provide `:hover` for desktops only.